# Is newest MONO prepared to Visual Basic 2010/2013?

Tags: vb.net, mono

MONO has a newest version 3.12 and I would like to know if I can run .NET 4.0 Visual Basic Form application on it. Basically I have a x64 .NET form program to access the .NET security libraries to perform AES encryption.

I tried to search for the answer in the MONO site (and GitHub) but I only had seen an old post about MONO 1.3.2 and VB.

Anyone know anything about it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Try it yourself and post what errors you meet. Since Micrsoft has released their VB.NET compiler as well as runtime as open source, Mono should be able to complete their VB.NET support soon.

Comment: Thank you Lex. I´ll be waiting as you recommend.